# Ansible hangs trying to resize existing partition using expect module

Tags: ansible, partitioning, pexpect

I am trying to resize /dev/sda2 partition

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0   50G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2          8:2    0 22.5G  0 part
  ├─rhel-root 253:0    0 20.1G  0 lvm  /
  └─rhel-swap 253:1    0  2.4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0            11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

so it will take the rest of /dev/sda disk. All works as expected when manually extending it and I've tried to automate it using ansible as I will have more than 40 exactly same servers which will need to have this partition resized.

I've tried to use PARTED module but didn't find a way to resize partition in use. So I figured that I can use expect module to manipulate input on "fdisk /dev/sda" command. Here is my playbook:

```
- name: Resize current partition on /dev/sda
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Install pexpect
      pip:
        name: pexpect

# Delete and create new partition on /dev/sda
    - name: create new partition
      expect:
        command: /sbin/fdisk /dev/sda
        responses:
          'Command.*$':
            - 'd'            
            - 'n'
            - 't'
            - 'w'
          'Partition number.*$': '\n' ## \n selects fdisk default choice ##
          'Select.*$': '\n'
          'First sector.*$': '\n'
          'Last sector.*$': '\n'
          'Do you want.*$': 'n' ## selects 'no' on removing LVM signature ##
          'Hex code.*$': '08e' ## selects LVM partition type ##
        echo: yes
        timeout: 10
      when: (ansible_os_family == "RedHat" and ansible_distribution_version|float >= 8)
```

I have launched it on my RHEL8 VM using localhost as inventory, after gathering facts and installing pexpect playbook freezes with no output. I have tried to launch ansible-playbook using -vvv and I receive no output after privilage escalation confirmation and it freezes:

```
<localhost> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/8a5a4c6a60"' -tt localhost '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-btnzvwwmzfnhezvghgjycpvwrorpkkpg ; /usr/libexec/platform-python /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1679001756.3663957-6375-69716906410504/AnsiballZ_expect.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create playbook that resizes last partition on /dev/sda which fullfills my use-cases

```
- name: Resize last partition on /dev/sda
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  vars:
    disk_name: '/dev/sda'

  tasks:
    - name: Read device information (always use unit when probing)
      parted: device={{ disk_name }} unit=MiB
      register: disk_info

    # - name: debug disk
    #   debug:
    #     msg: "Last partition is:  {{sdb_info.partitions | length}}"

    - name: Resize last partition
      parted:
        device: "{{ disk_name }}"
        number: "{{disk_info.partitions | length}}"
        part_end: "100%"
        resize: true
        state: present
```